# Optimizing the running speed of a large table with many formulae

Tags: performance, speed, optimize

I have to make an Excel-based calculator for other users. This works really simply, it just has to tell does a cell include certain letters or not.

**The calculator is basically a large table (downloadable at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq8zoxlmbtzu05a/table.xlsx?dl=0)):**

[image]

**Formulae look like this in columns B-D:**

```
=SUM(IF((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1);{"s","t"};"")));1;0))
```

The large table runs slow. Probably because of the long formula duplicated in thousands of cells?  **Is these a trick how to enhance the speed of such table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you want to use as few operations as possible and choose operations that run as fast as possible. In any way, until you try, you cannot really know.

First idea: try using functions SEARCH/FIND and combine them with nested IFs.

Second idea: try to first uppercase the string into a hidden column, then add 25 hidden columns (one for each letter of the alphabet) that are either 1 or 0 depending on condition if the string contains that particular letter. To get the result you want, you can then selectively add together the 0/1s from the corresponding letter columns. As a final step, add another column/formula to clip everything >0 to 1. Since the number of your queries is > 100 and there are only 25 letters, this might be faster than what you have now.

But to be honest with you, you are using the wrong tool for this type of problem. Using a database or a programming language would give you a speed increase by many orders of magnitude, and it could be easily be as drastic as 100000 : 1 or even more. For a better perspective, this is like going from 3 hours to 0.1 seconds.